# JPanel stacking multiple buttons

Tags: java, jpanel

How to stack multiple buttons on top of each other? The buttons should be positioned at the bottom of the application frame. I am trying to find a combination but with no luck, for example:

```
 final JPanel content = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
 content.add(chartPanel);
 content.add(button1, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
 content.add(button2, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
 setContentPane(content);
```

The buttons just overlap.

Comment: `content.add(button1, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);`?

Comment: I have a panel also. With button1 at PAGE_START I get button1 at the top, button2 at the button and the chart between them. Is it possible to get both buttons at the bottom?

Comment: Add the buttons to their own panel

Comment: Nice man, I totally forgot that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    final JPanel content = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    content.add(chartPanel);

    final JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    buttonPanel.add(button1, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    buttonPanel.add(button2, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    content.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    setContentPane(content);
```